# Django Rest Framework pagination extremely slow count

Tags: python, django, postgresql, pagination, django-rest-framework

I turned pagination on in Django Rest framework and it appears to be incredibly slow. Count looks like the culprit, and is taking hundreds of milliseconds to return each time due to the millions of rows in the tables.

I am using postgresql as the database. Is there any way to not count the rows and still use pagination? The performance was fine before this was enabled if I manually filtered the queryset.

Comment: Paste the code to make the question clearer.

Comment: There's not a whole lot in the way of code to paste. The only thing I added that makes it slow is this modification to settings.py:
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'api.pagination.StandardResultsSetPagination'

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Override the `get_paginated_response` method of your pagination class, and do not include the count. You can refer to the [base implementation](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/aa3f844b3d9d6f2bd192c7a711eca65dcbe2583e/rest_framework/pagination.py#165L) of the `PageNumberPagination` class to see what you should return.

```
from rest_framework.pagination import PageNumberPagination
from collections import OrderedDict # requires Python 2.7 or later

class PageNumberPaginationWithoutCount(PageNumberPagination):
    # Set any other options you want here like page_size

    def get_paginated_response(self, data):
        return Response(OrderedDict([
            ('next', self.get_next_link()),
            ('previous', self.get_previous_link()),
            ('results', data)
        ]))
```

Then in your `settings.py`, set `DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS` to your new pagination class.

```
DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS = 'path.to.PageNumberPaginationWithoutCount'
```

This approach is used in the [example in the pagination docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#example).

**Edit:** from the comments below it sounds like this might not be enough to prevent the slow sql query, so you might need to override `paginate_queryset` as well.

Comment: "Override the get_paginated_response method of your pagination class, and do not include the count." Seconded, yup. You may also want to consider using the CursorPagination for large datasets, as it wont get slower the further through the user pages, unlike the page and offset styles.

Comment: I tried that, and it removes the count from the result, but still runs it according to django debug toolkit. However, overriding paginate_queryset(self, queryset, request, view=None):

And setting self.count = 0 instead of self.count = _get_count(queryset) sorted it. I also just disabled next and previous as i don't need them.

Comment: How did you override paginate_queryset ?

Answer (score 20):

The issue is, that the query used to count is the same potentially complex one as used to fetch the data. That's rather wasteful. `PageNumberPagination` uses Django's own `Paginator` internally.

To make the query for the count simpler override the paginator class DRF uses:

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator
from django.utils.functional import cached_property
from rest_framework.pagination import PageNumberPagination

class FasterDjangoPaginator(Paginator):
    @cached_property
    def count(self):
        # only select 'id' for counting, much cheaper
        return self.object_list.values('id').count()


class FasterPageNumberPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    django_paginator_class = FasterDjangoPaginator
```

Comment: Very good solution, thanks! Will make my app a bit faster everywhere :)

Comment: Before using this everywhere, note that selecting an 'id' will change queries involving aggregation (the 'id', will be appended to whatever else you are grouping by).

Comment: After every new record, this needs to restart the application server to show the correct count. I think cached_property must not be used here.

Answer (score 6):

If you are ok without count, next and previous links, Following custom class can be used.

```
import sys
from collections import OrderedDict

from django.core.paginator import Paginator
from django.utils.functional import cached_property
from rest_framework.pagination import PageNumberPagination
from rest_framework.response import Response


class CustomPaginatorClass(Paginator):
    @cached_property
    def count(self):
        return sys.maxsize


# To Avoid large table count query, We can use this paginator class
class LargeTablePagination(PageNumberPagination):
    django_paginator_class = CustomPaginatorClass

    def get_paginated_response(self, data):
        return Response(OrderedDict([
            ('page', self.page.number),
            ('results', data)
        ]))
```

Comment: PageNumberPagination doesn't seem to have a django_paginator_class though?  Maybe it used to? This is on the right track though.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of a paginator that keeps the next/previous links working. It fetches an extra row at the end to check whether there is another page:

```py
class NoCountPagination(LimitOffsetPagination):
    def get_paginated_response(self, data):
        return Response(
            {
                "next": self.get_next_link(),
                "previous": self.get_previous_link(),
                "results": data,
            }
        )

    def paginate_queryset(self, queryset, request, view=None):
        self.offset = self.get_offset(request)
        self.limit = self.get_limit(request)

        # Get one extra element to check if there is a "next" page
        q = list(queryset[self.offset : self.offset + self.limit + 1])
        self.count = self.offset + len(q) if len(q) else self.offset - 1
        if len(q) > self.limit:
            q.pop()

        self.request = request
        if self.count > self.offset + self.limit and self.template is not None:
            self.display_page_controls = True

        return q

    def get_paginated_response_schema(self, schema):
        ret = super().get_paginated_response_schema(schema)
        del ret["properties"]["count"]
        return ret
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers either didn't work for me or were still performing the extra `COUNT(*)` query.

This will get rid of all pagination, the count query, and will just return the JSON response:

```
from rest_framework.pagination import PageNumberPagination


class NoCountPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = None

    def get_paginated_response(self, data):
        return Response({
            'results', data
        })
```

To use it:

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .models import MyModel
from .serializers import MySerializer


class CustomApiViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    """
    Simple viewset for viewing MyModels (as a list, or individually).
    """
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MySerializer
    pagination_class = NoCountPagination
```

Beware, this will return all rows from your queryset.  In almost all cases, I think it's probably better to just use `PageNumberPagination` as-is or maybe use @Florian's solution above to speed it up a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to getup8's response, I was able to get it working where it doesn't return the count but also doesn't return all of the rows (assuming you have PAGE_SIZE set to a reasonable number in your site's REST_FRAMEWORK settings).

```
from rest_framework.pagination import LimitOffsetPagination
    
class NoCountPaginator(LimitOffsetPagination):
    def get_count(self, queryset):
        return 99999999

    def get_paginated_response(self, data):
        return Response(OrderedDict([
            ('results', data)
        ]))
```

And to use it:

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .models import MyModel
from .serializers import MySerializer


class CustomApiViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MySerializer
    pagination_class = NoCountPaginator
```

I had PAGE_SIZE set to 25, so the API always returns only the top 25 rows and it no longer runs the count query.