# How do I wrap all metadata into a "meta" property?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

So I have a paginated list of results. Here's how DRF formats it by default:

```
{
    "count": 1023
    "next": "https://api.example.org/accounts/?page=5",
    "previous": "https://api.example.org/accounts/?page=3",
    "results": [
       …
    ]
}
```

How do I wrap all metadata into a "meta" property so that the response looks like this:

```
{
    "meta": {
        "count": 1023
        "next": "https://api.example.org/accounts/?page=5",
        "previous": "https://api.example.org/accounts/?page=3",
    },
    "results": [
       …
    ]
}
```

---

EDIT: Thanks Alasdair for your answer. Here's how I did it:

```
from rest_framework import pagination
from rest_framework.response import Response

class CustomPagination(pagination.LimitOffsetPagination):

  def get_paginated_response(self, data):
    return Response({
      'meta': {
        'next': self.get_next_link(),
        'previous': self.get_previous_link(),
        'count': self.count
      },
      'results': data
    })
```

Comment: You can create a custom paginator and override the `get_paginated_response` method. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31740039/django-rest-framework-pagination-extremely-slow-count/31741778#31741778) should get you started, please update your question if you get stuck.

Comment: You should post solution as an answer, not as edit to your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [**implement a custom pagination style**](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#custom-pagination-styles) to wrap all the metadata into a meta property.

**Step-1 Implement a custom pagination class:**

First, we will implement a custom pagination class `WrappedMetadataPagination` which will inherit from `pagination.LimitOffsetPagination`. In that, we will override the `get_paginated_response()` and specify our custom pagination output style.

```
class WrappedMetadataPagination(pagination.LimitOffsetPagination):
    """
    This custom pagination class wraps the metadata about the results 
    like 'next', 'previous' and 'next' keys into a dictionary with key as 'meta'.
    """

    def get_paginated_response(self, data):
        return Response({
            'meta': { # wrap other keys as dictionary into 'meta' key
                'next': self.get_next_link(),
                'previous': self.get_previous_link(),
                'count': self.count
            },
            'results': data
        })
```

**Step-2 Setup the custom class in DRF settings:**

After implementing the custom class, you need to specify this custom pagination class in your DRF settings.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'my_project.my_app.pagination.WrappedMetadataPagination', # specify the custom pagination class
...       
}
```